# How can I use Turkish characters in Nodejs module Regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I want use [bad-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words) module with Turkish characters but i cant use. How can i make this?

Sample:

```
var Filter = require("bad-words")

var filter = new Filter({ replaceRegex:  /[A-Za-z0-9가-힣_]/g }); 
//multilingual support for word filtering

filter.addWords('ğ', 'ü', 'ı', 'i', 'e', 'y');

filter.clean("Turkish: ğ ü ı English: i e y");
```

output: "Turkish: ğ ü ı English: * * *"

Try it on npm RunKit: https://npm.runkit.com/bad-words

Comment: [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150078/16940103) might help, using Unicode's instead of the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bad-words` library does not support non-ascii letters, as it uses the ascii `\b` for word-boundary. Non-ascii are not even considered letters.

You can see [here](https://github.com/web-mech/badwords/pull/110/files) a proposal for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

if the RegEx engine supports Unicode then you can try to match the unicode instead of characters. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2371780/10938383)